# CSS round in half circular position link

Tags: css

I'm really a noob with web designing. I don't have much knowledge with CSS but I have been given a task to create a button like this

[image]

I really don't know how can I create a round link in this form. Please help me.

Comment: Is this one button, or 3 buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul class="smenu">
<li class="smenuitem"><a href="http://ux.stackexchange.com/"></a></li>
<li class="smenuitem"><a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com/"></a></li>
<li class="smenuitem"><a href="http://www.webmasters.stackexchange.com/"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Style

```
li.smenuitem a, li.smenuitem a:link:hover, li.smenuitem a:visited, li.smenuitem a:visited:hover {
display: block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Not exact same but something you can play with. http://jsfiddle.net/J2XTs/

Comment: How do I create the line?

Comment: You may use SVG line.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you also use image map tag (html).
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap